# Do questions come before or after art activity?

Tags: aesthetics

Do questions generate art activity or only follow art activity?
Most art is a form of assertion not of questioning.  In thqt wiew, art is not an
answer to a question, but a statement of experience.  If not, when & how does art emerge from question asking, rom particular questions or kinds of questions?